# Xcode Conversion

Tags: objective-c

i am facing the problem in converting nsstring to nsdate can any one Help me out in this

How to convert this string "Mon, 10 Dec 2012 08:00:00 CST" to NSDate in Objective-c

Comment: And please search there are thousands of similar questions there in stack **overflow**  flooded with answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
NSString *dateString=@"Mon, 10 Dec 2012 08:00:00 CST";
NSDate *date=[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:dateString];

NSLog(@"Date is %@",date);
```

Output:

```
Date is 2012-12-10 08:00:00 -0600
```